# Why does my email look like s**t in outlook?

Tags: html, email, outlook, rendering

I am working on an email right now, which is mostly based on images. The email looks good if you open it with the browser, but very bad, if opened with Outlook. I heard that Outlook uses some sort of rendering process. Is that true? What can I do to protect my email from getting smashed?

Have a look at my email: http://www.s4ea.org/invite.html

Were my email does and does not work: https://litmus.com/tests/16706239/versions/1/screenshots

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Invitation</title>
<style>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.wrapper {
    width:30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.slim {
    background-color: #B63538;
    margin:0 0 2px 0;
}

.logo {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.text {
    margin:2px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
}

.text img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.facebook {
    margin:2px 0 0 0;
}

.facebook img {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}

.contact nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.sports { 
    margin:2px 0 0 0;
}

.sports img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}   

.contact {
    background-color:#fb9648;
    height:auto;
    margin:2px 0 0 0;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.contact img {
    padding-left:12%;
    margin-bottom:5%;
}

.contact nav {
    background-color: #fb9648;
    height:50px;
}

.contact nav ul .bild, .contact nav ul .text, .contact nav ul .spacer {
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}

.bild {
    width:15%;
    height:auto;
}

.contact nav ul .bild img {
    width: 40px;
    height:auto;
}

.contact nav ul .spacer {
    width: 5%;
}

.contact nav ul .text {
    height:40px;
    width: 30%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 10cm) and (max-width: 18cm)
{

    .wrapper {
        width:80%;
    }



}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1cm) and (max-width: 10cm)

{
    .wrapper {
        width:100%;
    }

    .contact img {
        width:80%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }   

}



</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="slim">&nbsp;

    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.taste4sports.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.taste4sports.com/images/logo_email.jpg"  />
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="text">
    <a href="http://www.taste4sports.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.s4ea.org/images/text4.jpg" />
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="facebook">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/SPORTS4ea?ref=ts&fref=ts" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.s4ea.org/images/facebook7.jpg" />
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="sports">
        <a href="http://www.s4ea.org" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://www.taste4sports.com/images/support.jpg" />
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="wrapper">
    <tr>
    <td class="contact">
        <img src="http://www.taste4sports.com/images/contact/phone.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.taste4sports.com/images/contact/fax.jpg" />
            <a href="http://www.taste4sports.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.s4ea.org/images/internet_back2.jpg" />
            </a>
        <a href="mailto:clara@s4ea.org">
            <img src="http://www.s4ea.org/images/@.jpg" />
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your second link goes to a login page, not a screen shot...

Comment: Because Outlook wants you to suffer

Answer (score 1):

MS Outlook uses Microsoft Word to render HTML email. Unfortunately, support for even sparse formatting can be sketchy, depending on the version of Outlook that is used by subscribers. First, determine what your most important customers are using (if you use MailChimp or another service, it can tell you the demographic data)… this will give you a look into what kinds of CSS features are supported.

Reference: http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/previews-and-tests/my-campaign-looks-bad-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

Some of your css may not be supported. Check out this site for a css suppport matrix that may point to something being left out:

[CSS Support for Outlook](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML for email unfortunately doesn't follow the same standards as webpages, and support for older MS email clients can be just as bad as supporting older versions of IE. Check out the [HTML E-mail Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) with a CSS reset and template that would be ideal for starting a newsletter that won't look like s**t.